# Elsticsearch - Limit number of results that matches a separate condition

Tags: elasticsearch

Does Elasticsearch have a mechanism to query for documents while limiting that only a number of those documents match a separate condition?

I have a collection of documents that have a field indicating a category. Is it possible to query for 100 documents that matches some criteria, while limiting that no more than 20 of those documents have category=A? A similar scenario would be to query for 100 documents while specifying that 20 documents must be of category=A, 30 of category=B and 50 of category C.

Comment: AFAIK, out of the box, in a single query, there is no such feature. But what is the intent?

Comment: Thanks, just wondering if there is a feature to achieve better performance than doing multiple queries.

Comment: But you didn't answer the question. What is the intent? Typically, this should be a faceting option for user to select, which category they want to see in the search response, if they want to filter it down to specific category. Else, you can use boosting to get specific category a higher priority in search response. But all depends on what is your requirement?

Comment: Thanks, will give you a concrete example. The requirement is to show news articles (in a paginated way), those news should match some criteria, user preferences, etc, but with a hard restriction of not including more than N news of "politics" category per page.

Comment: If I were designing the API, I would let it only return data for specific category. UI could be calling the same API with different category filters and build that part of the results section based on however they want to split it. So this way, you keep the API generic enough to be reused for different configuration. Add size/count support to the API so that it can support pagination as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to  get different number of documents per category in a single query .Using [msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)
    You can execute several searches within single api request

```
    GET index85/_msearch
    {}
    {"query" : {"term" : { "category.keyword": "Political"}},"from":0,"size":15}
    {}
    {"query" : {"term" : { "category.keyword": "Sports"}},"from":0,"size":5}
```

Comment: Hey! I guess my question is quite similar to this one, so I forward it here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425695/elasticsearch-limit-a-part-of-the-results-hits